# Is there any way to keep track of all js files created by gulp-rev in rev-mainfest.json file?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rev

I am using gulp-rev to generate minified js files. Now gulp-rev only keep track of last revision in rev-mainfest.json file e.g

```
{
   "product-min.js": "product-min.a2720ef6.js"
}
```

But I want to keep track of all generated files e.g

```
 {
   "product-min.js": "product-min.a2720ef6.js",
   "product-min.js": "product-min.1f2j3jfj.js"
   "product-min.js": "product-min.33ffsfsd.js"
   .....
 }
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: this manifest file needs to just contain a single file with key "product-min.js" for proper referencing. what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not possible with gulp-rev.